Why does my VB.Net keep losing the databinding connection
I have taken the advice from people here and I am starting to using DataBindings, but it keeps losing connection.
I have a created a form, I then add a component from the Project tab, Data, Dataset (Default DataSet1.xsd). It creates the tab, I then go to Server Explorer, Add the connection, test the connection and it passes, then drag and drop the table that I am using onto the DataSet1.xsd tab. I go back to my form in designer, then I drag and drop the binding source icon from the Toolbox, to the bottom of the form. The wizard keeps a small box open, then I go to my ID textbox that corelates to the ID from the table, then I go to properties, DataBindings, text, then when I click on the dropdown arrow it keeps coming up with the error The connection to the server has been lost. I then have to close the Designer and reopen the form in designer, and the DindingSource is gone, I readd it and go teh the properties on the on the BindingsSource and Datasource is none, if I try to add the Datasorce from here, the same thing, The connection to the server has been lost.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wron

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/NETWinForms:-cleaning-a-solution-remov/10698782?q=databinding

Consider getting ahead by using the legacy .NET framework.  Pick the project template with ".NET Framework" in its name.

Hi Hans tried that and no joy, I'm still playing around trying to figure it out. BTW, I am not a programmer, just a retired toolmaker, who enjoys learning this stuff.

Hi Folks, I have spent 2 days trying to figure this out with no luck, is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

The issue was using the original System.Data.SqlClient, I changed to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and the connection was held.
